# How to clear the activity stack in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having a requirement where i can press a logout button from any activity in the application,the thing is when I press the logout button I need to get the `login` screen without showing the previous activities. I am using:

```
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP )
```

I am starting the activity like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  try
  {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
      v.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(intent);
      intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
      removeSessionFiles();
      //startActivity (new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity1.class));
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    String str = e.toString();
  }
}
```

I get to the `login` screen when I press the `logout` button, but when I press `back` button on the device it is showing the previous activities - I should go to the Android home screen when I press back button in the `login` screen. Please can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: show how you are starting the activity... because setting the above flag will do the work...

Comment: Why don't you use startActivity to load the login activity and finish the current activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dinash said above the flag should be set before the activity is started...whats the point of setting the flag after starting the activity....the code should look something like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
      v.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(intent);

      removeSessionFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

ho man just put the flag setting line just before the startactivity line... This wil solve your problem...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Yes,it solved my prob but still another is there,i.e when i go through 3-4 activities and then press the logout button its not driving me to the login screen instead its taking me to the last activity again and if i pres the logout button again now then its giving the login screen .this is the problem can you find me a solution for this please.

Answer (score 0):

setFlags before calling startActivity will solve your problem

```
public void onClick(View v) {

try { 
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ); 
v.getRootView().getContext().startActivity(intent);
removeSessionFiles(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
String str = e.toString();
}
}
```